# Removing non alphanumeric characters from a string in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out how to remove characters that are not alphanumeric in C from first principles and I've almost figured it out but not quite. The code is below with a final print statement to compare my sorted to unsorted strings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
   char inputString[50];
   scanf("%[^\n]%*c", inputString);
   char holderString[50];
   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;
   while (i <= strlen(inputString)+1) {
    if (((inputString[i] >= 101) && (inputString[i] <= 132)) || ((inputString[i] >= 141) && (inputString[i] <= 172)))   {

      holderString[j] = inputString[i];
      j+=1;
    } i+=1;
   } printf("%s\n", holderString);
   printf("%s\n", inputString);

   return 0;
```

When I try an expression like "Hello world!" I get "elloworl" which lead me to add the +1 to the strlen(inputString) but to no avail. I try other input strings and it seems almost at random which characters my program decides to remove in addition to the non-alphanumeric ones. A lot of the time it is characters in a sequence like abcd I noticed, but I tried increasing the bounds but this doesn't help (and why should it, since these are the correct ASCII bounds according to the tables I have  checked). Any advice?

Comment: Why isn't your `while` condition `i < strlen(inputString)`?

Comment: Those codes you are using are the `octal` representation, they should be `decimal`, anyway, it's better to use the character literals instead of the codes.

Comment: Have you run your program in a debugger and stepped thru your code line by line? A few small tips: Don't use magic numbers for the ascii values. All your values are wrong. `101` is not `A`. You are looking at the octal column instead of the decimal one. Use the literal `'A`' instead to avoid such errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integer bounds you gave don't match the ASCII codes.  For example, `'H'` is 72.

As the commenters suggest, instead of reading up on the ASCII table, you should use `char` literals.  So,

```
if ( ( inputString[i] >= 'A' && inputString[i] <= 'Z' )
        || ( inputString[i] >= 'a' && inputString[i] <= 'z' )
        || ( inputString[i] >= '0' && inputString[i] <= '9' ) ) {
```

You could also avoid all of this by using `isalnum` from ctype.h.

Comment: `isalnum` is good advice, the OP seems to have forgotten the num part, in the code.

Comment: This is the best advice it points out fundamental problems rather than just giving a simple answer that doesn't help in the long run thank you for the response